# Do having documents of almost same size inside a collection in MongoDB improves the performance?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am designing the schema for a blogging web-app. On home page I have to show the list of posts displaying only title, subtitle, date & author for each post. On clicking an item in the list I have to show the corresponding complete post.
To do that I am using 2 schemas([postInfo & postBody](https://gist.github.com/ivish/d80a503de774fb053ea5)), so that my documents can have almost same size in collections corresponding to the schemas. Will this improve the performance in some sense? Let's say when I query for list of posts, Will MongoDB  complete the operation fast because document size will be almost same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will MongoDB complete the operation (query) fast because document size will be almost same.

No. Document size similarity has no effect whatsoever on query performance. Average document size - yes (fetching larger documents will obviously be more expensive), but not the size similarity.

> To do that I am using 2 schemas(blogInfo & blogBody)

I assume you mean `postInfo` and `postBody`. In this case, don't do that. It will only complicate your code. Store all post data in the same document. When you don't need the body (rendering index on the main page), just don't fetch it. In case you didn't know it, mongodb supports fetching subset of document fields (just title and excerpt, for example).

Document size similarity matters when there's high churn in the collection: documents are being frequently deleted and inserted. In this case, documents being the same size will reduce fragmentation of data files. This is not the case for your typical blog.

Comment: Thanks.. As @Markus W Mahilberg mentioned that MongoDB allocates a buffer for the document to read by using document's length property. So, If I opt out from receiving body for home page will the buffer allocated will be of small size or same size.. If it's of same size then it will for sure effect the performance of server.. I am sorry if I am being too naive.. I m new to this

Comment: @Vishal: you, being new, don't need to worry about such low-level database implementation details, much less *design your app* around them. For all practical purposes that performance hit does not exist.

Comment: @Vishal: all performance optimizations should be backed by __hard numbers__. So I advise you to build both schemas, measure their performances and choose one.

Comment: Is there any tool that can help to generate **hard numbers**?

Comment: @Vishal: don't know about node.js tech. There must be something.

Comment: @Vishal I can only second Sergio here as for not doing premature optimization, which as we all know is the root of pure evil. I fail to see where a performance gain could be reached, though.

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple: No. An index saves the starting position of a document with a certain value for the index key. When the index is searched (btree) and I he key matches, MongoDB jumps to said position in the data file, reads the document length header, allocates an according buffer, then reads binary form of the document and unmarshals it. As you can see, the only thing where document size matters is in allocating memory. Once. In a scenario where the data is not in the in-memory working set.

Now let us assume you don't have an index. How would a matching doc be found? Well, actually pretty easy: the same process is repeated for each and every document of the whole collection - a massive operation in which the allocation of a buffer simply pales because it is orders of magnitude (yes, plural) faster than even reading from SSD.

How to model that? The answer is pretty easy: it is a one-to-one relation, so it should be written in a single document.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any reference for your answer will be really appreciated